# Given PRNG $G(s)$, why is $G(s) || G(s+1)$ not a PRNG?

Tags: random-number-generator, pseudo-random-function, pseudo-random-generator

I have given a pseudorandom Generator $G(s)$, $|s|=n$ whose expansion $l(n)$ is $>2n$. I also know that $G^\prime(s) := G(s_1,\ldots,s_{\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor})$ is a pseudorandom generator. Now the function

$\begin{equation}L(s) := G(s) ~||~ G(s+1)\end{equation}$

with $||$ being concatenation is supposed to be no pseudorandom generator and I struggle to prove it. Intuitively, I would think that since $L$ passes two different seeds to $G$ and $G$ is pseudorandom, $L$ must be pseudorandom too. $G(s+1)$ should be unpredictably different from $G(s+1)$ for a PRNG, should it not? Could someone point me into the right direction?

Comment: I missed the fact that you mix the terms PRG, PRF and PRNG. They are all different. Which does the problem actually concern?

Comment: I am not sure what the difference is, but I would label it PRNG.

Comment: The tag wikis (click tag, then learn more) have some info and Wikipedia has decent articles about them too.

Comment: You probably want the probabilities of individual bits being 0 or 1 to be equal, a uniform distribution at the bit level.  But the construction `L(s) := G(s) || G(s+1)` gives a 1 in the *k*th place iff *either* the same place in `G(s)` gets a 1.  If the samples `G(s)` and `G(s+1)` were uncorrelated, then the probability of a 1 in any specific position of `L(s)` would be 0.75 rather than 0.5.  Whether the bias violates your meaning of PRNG, I don't really know (since you do not give your definition).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually came up with an answer myself.

Since $|G^\prime| > 2n$, we assume 
$$\begin{align*}
   L(s) & = G^\prime(s) ~||~ G^\prime(s+1)  \\
        & = G(s_1,\ldots,s_{\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor}) ~||~ G^\prime(s+1) \\
        & = G(s_1,\ldots,s_{\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor}) ~||~ G(s^\prime) \\
        & = G(s_1,\ldots,s_{\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor}) ~||~ G(s^\prime_1,\ldots,s^\prime_{\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor}) \\
\end{align*}$$

Let $D(K)$ be a Distinguisher with
$$\begin{equation*}
   D(K) = 
   \begin{cases}
      1 & \text{if $k_1,\ldots,k_{\frac{n}{2}} = k_{\frac{n}{2} + 1},\ldots,k_n$} \\
      0 & \text{else}
   \end{cases}
\end{equation*}$$

$|K|$ must be even for strings generated by $L$, being the concatenation of two equally long strings. Strings with odd length can thus be immediately identified as random and thus uninteresting.

Adding $1$ to $s$, the probability that a bit in the first half changes is equal to the probability that all bits in the second half are $1$. For $D$ to output $0$ on a string generated by $L$, exactly that case must occur as the second half is cut off and ignored.
$$\begin{equation*}
   P(\text{bit $i$ flipped with $i>\frac{n}{2}$}) = \frac{1}{2^{\frac{n}{2}}},
\end{equation*}$$
because the lower $\frac{n}{2}$ bits must be $1$.

Hence
$$\begin{equation*}
   P(D(G(s)) = 1) = 1 - P(D(G(s)) = 0) = 1 - \frac{1}{2^\frac{n}{2}}
\end{equation*}$$

The probability that in a uniformly random bistring $r$ the upper and lower half are identical (which leads to an erroneous output $D(r)$) is the ratio between the number of possible bitrings with equal halves and all possible bistrings. For half a string, there are $2^{\frac{n}{2}}$ possibilities wo this is also the number of possibilities for strings with equal halves, with $2^n$ total strings.

$$\begin{equation*}
   P(D(r) = 1) = \frac{2^{\frac{n}{2}}}{2^n} = 2^{-\frac{n}{2}} = \frac{1}{2^\frac{n}{2}}
\end{equation*}$$

Furthermore
$$\begin{equation*}
   \left\lvert P(D(G(s)) = 1) - P(D(r) = 1) \right\rvert = \left\lvert1 - \frac{1}{2^\frac{n}{2}} -
   \frac{1}{2^\frac{n}{2}}\right\rvert = 1 - \frac{2}{2^{\frac{n}{2}}} = 1 -
   \frac{1}{2^{\frac{n}{2} - 1}}
\end{equation*}$$

This is non-negligible and increases with increasing $n$.
$L$ is therefore not necessarily pseudorandom.

Comment: A beautiful proof!

Comment: @oarfish I don't really understand... Isn't the output of function $L$ behaves just like a pad generated in a CTR cipher (except for $IV$ does not participate in pad directly, but this is another question)? And I also believe that when $s+1$, the probability of "the first half does **not** change" is equal to the probability of "all bits in the second half are $1$". Or the probability "**a** bit in the first half changes" is equal to ${}_{\frac{n}{2}}C_1/2^{\frac{n}{2}}$.

Answer (score 6):

$L$ is *not necessarily* a pseudorandom generator, but it may be. Hence, there is no hope of proving that $L$ is not a pseudorandom generator from what you are given. Rather, you must exhibit a pseudorandom generator $G$ such that $L$ is not a pseudorandom generator. Here is the canonical example with expansion factor $n+1$.

Let $f$ be a one-way permutation (*i.e.*, an injective, length-preserving one-way function). Then it is known that the following is a pseudorandom generator with expansion factor $n+1$:

> - Choose uniformly a seed $s$ of even length $s_1s_2\dots s_{2n}$.
> - Compute $b = \sum_{i=1}^n s_is_{n+i}$ (with arithmetic in $\mathbf{F}_2$).
> - Output $f(s_1s_2\dots s_n)s_{n+1}s_{n+2}\dots s_{2n}b$.

Now, if $s$ is uniformly chosen, with probability $1/2$ its last bit will be $0$, meaning that $s+1$ will be just $s$ with the last bit ($s_{2n}$) flipped, and in turn it means that $G(s+1)$ will equal $G(s)$ except possibly in the last two bits. Hence, a distinguisher can check whether the second half of its input string equals the first one disregarding the last two bits of each. If the string is $G(s)G(s+1)$, this happens with probability at least $1/2$, whereas if the string is truly random this happens with probability $1/2^{n-2}$.

Comment: Can you give a source for why *it is known*?

Comment: Any good cryptography textbook (*e.g.*, Goldreich or Katz-Lindell).

Comment: @fkraiem I don't think this construction is a pseudorandom generator. Since a distinguisher can always compute the last bit $b$ as described. For a uniform string the probability for last bit to be $\sum_{i=1}^n{s_is_{n+i}}$ is only $1\over2$. And as you mentioned, in Katz's book a similar construction is presented as a **counterexample**.

Comment: @wangkaibule No, a distinguisher cannot compute $b$, since it does not know the seed (by virtue of $f$'s one-wayness).

Comment: @wangkaibule The generator does not output $s_1\dots s_n$; it outputs $f(s_1\dots s_n)$.

Answer (score 4):

I would like to improve upon @fkraiem answer (i.e. give a simpler construction):

```
you must exhibit a pseudorandom generator G such that L is not a pseudorandom generator.
```

Take any pseudorandom number generator $PRG : \{0,1\}^{n-1} \rightarrow \{0,1\}^{l(n)}$.
Now define $G : \{0,1\}^n \rightarrow \{0,1\}^{l(n)}$ to be $G(x_1 | x_2 ... | x_n) = PRG(x_1 | x_2 ... | x_{n-1})$.

I.e. $G$ ignores the last input bit and passes the truncated key to $PRG$.

$G$ is a pseudorandom number generator but $L = G(s)|G(s+1)$ is not:

Let's construct a distinguisher  $D$ that given a number $x = x_1 | x_2 | ... | x_{2l(n)}$ tells whether it was sampled uniformly at random, or whether it was generated from $L$:

```
# our distinguisher
fun D(x):
    if the first half of x equals to the second half of x:
        return 1
    else
        return 0
```

If $x = r$ is a truly random number, then $\Pr[D(r) = 1] = 2^{-l(n)}$

If $x = L(s)$ was generated using $L$ from a random key $s = s_1|s_2|...|s_n$, then at least half of the time G(s) is identical to G(s+1) (because half of the time the last bit $s_n = 0$) and so at least half of the time the distinguisher $D$ outputs 1, thus the difference

$|\Pr[D(G(s)) = 1] - \Pr[D(r) = 1]| \geq \frac{1}{2} - 2^{-l(n)}$ is not negligible.

Comment: You might add a note about the endianness you're assuming for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

Here's yet another proof. The idea is to use $L$ against itself!
Suppose $L(s)$ is PRG, so we can use it in place of $G$, which will lead to:
$$H(s)=L(s)\|L(s+1)=G(s)\|G(s+1)\|G(s+1)\|G(s+2)$$
Since the second and third parts are the same, a distinguisher can be made easily and $H$ won't be PRG and by contradiction we get that $L$ is not PRG.